# How can add custom EntityState enum

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My project use soft delete but one database table i should not use soft delete. I want this row delete in database table. My soft delete function do check "entitystate" and add current date for deletedat cell in this record.

I want add new entitystate enum. How can do this?

```
var deletedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();
        deletedEntities.ForEach(e =>
        {
            try
            {
                e.Property("DeletedAt").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
                e.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a new state value is not the correct course of action, create a new Interface e.g. ISoftDeletable and filter entities with it

```
var deletedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == 
                    EntityState.Deleted && e.Entity is ISoftDeletable).ToList();

deletedEntities.ForEach(e =>
    {
        try
        {
            e.Property("DeletedAt").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            e.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {

        }
    });
```